# Income tax exemption on gifts given to parents in India

Tags: india, gifts, inr-indian-rupee

Assuming that if a person has a total taxable income of INR 20 lacs, and that person gifts his parents jewellery worth INR 2 lacs. Does the total taxable income of the individual reduce ? If yes, by how much amount ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't get a reduction of taxable income for gifts given to anybody, but, *in general*, gifts are taxable income for the *recipients* (with some exemptions such as wedding gifts). For jewelry, gifts above INR 50,000 are taxable (at rates applying to "Income from Other Sources") at Fair Market Value.

**However**, gifts from relatives are exempt from taxation, and so your parents don't owe any tax on the jewelry that you gift them. On the other hand, you don't get to deduct the value of the gift from *your* income subject to tax.